# How can I change the color of the ion-title?

Tags: html, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, ionic3

I try to change color of the ion-title in ionic 2.

I have this following code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
   <ion-title primary>Title</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

The color of the `ion-title` don't change. I try several things like:

```
<ion-title color="primary">Title</ion-title> 
<ion-title> 
    <p primary>Title</p>
</ion-title>
```

With the second I have the title in the right color, but the header is big. So I add this in the variables.scss:

```
$toolbar-ios-height: 5rem; // ios
$toolbar-md-height: 5rem;  // android
```

But nothing change.Does anyone have a solution? Or do I have to use the `p` or `h` tag to change the color?

Comment: Are you testing on a mobile device ? If so, do you rebuild your project before running it ?
Or are you using `ionic serve` ?
Try to work with `Cache Disable` on your browser option.

Comment: I try on preview, device and emulator. The $toolbar works, I try it, but not with the p or h tag. Just when I have ion-title

Comment: do you need a global change or for one page?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Remove the `color="..."` from the `ion-title` element and use this sass variables in your `variables.scss` file:

```
$toolbar-md-title-text-color: #777;
$toolbar-ios-title-text-color: #777;
$toolbar-wp-title-text-color: #777;
```

If you want to use one the colors included in the named color variables

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #488aff,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,

  ...

  custom:     #777
);
```

You can do it by using `map-get` like this:

```
$toolbar-md-title-text-color: map-get($colors, custom);
$toolbar-ios-title-text-color: map-get($colors, custom);
$toolbar-wp-title-text-color: map-get($colors, custom);
```

**Note:**

Setting the color with *just* the `color` attribute has been deprecated since the 3.0.0 version of Ionic [more info](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes).

**Update:**

> [...] all the element on the navbar change color, Can we just change
>   the ion-title? Or have a second variable to change the other elements?

You can add this style rule in the `app.scss` file (to make it global) and it will only change the title and nothing else:

```
.toolbar-title.toolbar-title-md, 
.toolbar-title.toolbar-title-ios, 
.toolbar-title.toolbar-title-wp { color: map-get($colors, custom); }
```

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again, but all the element on the navbar change color, Can we just change the ion-title ? Or have a second variable to change the other elements ?

Comment: Don't worry, we're here to help :) Seems like a bug, but in any case, instead of using the sass variable, you can add this style rule in the app.scss file (to make it global) and it will only change the title and nothing else: 
`.toolbar-title.toolbar-title-md, .toolbar-title.toolbar-title-ios, .toolbar-title.toolbar-title-wp { color: map-get($colors, custom); }`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This combine with the previous I have exactly what I want, have a good day :)

Comment: That's great! I've updated the answer with the last comments

Answer (score 6):

I know this question has been answered, but an another way to set the text colour in the title is in the variables.scss file,

```
$colors: (
    calm: (
      base: #000,
      contrast: #ffc900
    ),
   etc..
);



<ion-navbar color="calm">
    <ion-title>Some Text</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

base will be your background colour and contrast will be your text/icon colour

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, I wanted to change the ion-title color on a specific page not globally.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, one can use something like this:

```
ion-toolbar { --color: #940000 }
```

Set the color as you wish; put in *.scss file.

Enjoy!